# OpenRefine capitalize first letter of all entries within a cell on a TSV

Tags: csv, openrefine, capitalize, grel

How do I capitalize the first letter of the first word of each entry within a cell on a TSV? For example is there a function to make 'Dogs||cats||fish' change to 'Dogs||Cats||Fish' and do the same to all cells on the TSV?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming your dataset looks like this:

| All | Column 1 | Column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | Dogs||cats||fish | Apples||oranges |
|  | Elephants||tigers | Peaches||bananas |

Usually you would just apply [toTitlecase()](https://docs.openrefine.org/manual/grelfunctions#totitlecases) to each cell. But this would not work on your data because the words are not separated by whitespace but by the separator `||`.

So you could either replace your separater `||` with whitespaces, apply `toTitlecase()` and replace the whitespaces again with your separator:

```
value.replace("||", "   ").toTitlecase().replace("   ", "||")
```

**Note:** I am explicitly replacing `||` with three whitespaces to avoid confusion with possibly whitespace separated words like `Great white shark`.

Or you could split on your seperator, perform the `toTitlecase()` operation and join the results back together.

```
forEach(value.split("||"), v, v.toTitlecase()).join("||")
```

To perform this on all cells on the whole dataset you can use the "All => Transform" dialog. "All" is the pseudo column you find on the left, where you can also star or flag single rows.

Comment: The second formula is more reliable, in my opinion.